# Forge Migrate CodeIgniter 4 Foreign Key Error

Tags: php, codeigniter, migrate, codeigniter-4

When using or migrating Codeigniter to generate the relationship in the code below appears or error

Migrate Product

```
public function up()
{

    $this->forge->addField([
        'id'            => [
            'type'           => 'INT',
            'unsigned'       => TRUE,
            'auto_increment' => TRUE
        ],
        'categories_id' => [
            'type'          => 'INT'
        ],
        'product'       => [
            'type'          => 'VARCHAR',
            'constraint'    => '255'
        ]
    ]);
    $this->forge->addKey('id', TRUE);
    $this->forge->createTable('products');
    $this->forge->addForeignKey('categories_id', 'categories', 'id');

}
```

Migrate Categories

```
$this->forge->addField([
        'id'            => [
            'type'           => 'INT',
            'unsigned'       => TRUE,
            'auto_increment' => TRUE
        ],
        'category'      => [
            'type'          => 'VARCHAR',
            'constraint'    => '255'
        ],
        'ordination'    => [
            'type'          => 'INTEGER'
        ],
        'isactive'      => [
            'type'          => 'INTEGER',
            'default'       => 1
        ]
    ]);

    $this->forge->addKey('id', TRUE);
    $this->forge->createTable('categories');
```

Error

> Type:        CodeIgniter\Database\Exceptions\DatabaseException
>   Message:     Field `categories_id` not found.

Answer (score 1):

Problem with this code is that after calling

```
$this->forge->createTable('products');
```

It will reset the query object, so it will lose the reference to the table and will not find that particular field you are looking for. So change the order of your query like this :

```
$this->forge->addForeignKey('categories_id', 'categories', 'id');
$this->forge->createTable('products');
```